# Simple string assignment causing a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault, c++14, ncurses

I've tracked this problem through a lot my classes, and it surprised me, that the source of this error is a simple `std::string = std::string` operation.

I won't post the whole code, just the functions that are executed in sequence. I still think that there is too much code for SO standards, but I see no other option.

Some context notes:

- OrderedPair is a public struct `{ int y, int x }` in a separate `lib.inc` file.
- Leading underscore marks a variable declared in the function header
- Trailing underscore marks a class member variable

### ncefm.cc -- basically the main file

```
std::vector<std::string> juststring = {"teststring", "another string", "foobar"};
List* list0 = new List(w0_, juststring); // Source of the error
```

### list.cc -- constructor `List()` is called here

Just ignore the optional variables, they aren't called anyway

```
List::List(Frame* const _parent, std::vector<std::string> &_list,
  const OrderedPair &_pos = {0, 0}, const unsigned int &_spacing = 1,
  const unsigned int &_maxsize = 0) {
  pos_ = _pos;
  size_ = _list.size();
  spacing_ = _spacing;
  maxsize_ = _maxsize;
  parent_ = _parent;

  Fill(_list); //Source of the error

  Redraw();

  parent_->AddWidget(this);
}
```

#### list.cc -- Member function Fill()

list_ is a member variable of type std::vector

```
void List::Fill(std::vector<std::string> &_list) {
  for (unsigned int loop = size_; loop < (size_ + _list.size()); loop++) {
    list_.push_back(new Label(parent_, _list[loop], {pos_.y + (loop * spacing_),
      pos_.x}, maxsize_)); // source of the error (the constructor Label() )
  }
}
```

### label.cc -- constructor Label() is called here

```
Label::Label(Frame* const _parent, std::string &_text,
  const OrderedPair &_pos = {0,0}, const unsigned int &_maxsize = 0) {
  pos_ = _pos;
  maxsize_ = _maxsize;
  parent_ = _parent;

  SetText(_text); // Source of the error

  parent_->AddWidget(this);
}
```

#### list.cc -- Member function SetText()

Here we finally are, the source of the error is...

```
void Label::SetText(std::string& _text) {
  if (maxsize_ != 0 && _text.length() > maxsize_) _text.resize(maxsize_);
  text_ = _text; // THIS?!
  size_ = text_.length();

  Redraw();
}
```

If I just comment out this line, the error dissapears,
  of course, that defeats the functionality.
text_.assign(_text); doesn't work either.

### label.h -- To show the header file and definition of some variable `text_`

```
class Label {
private:
  OrderedPair pos_;

  unsigned int size_;
  unsigned int maxsize_;
  std::string text_;
  Frame* parent_;

public:
  Label(Frame* const _parent, std::string &_text, const OrderedPair &_pos,
    const unsigned int &_maxsize);
  ~Label();

  inline const Frame* GetParent();
  inline unsigned int GetSize();

  inline std::string Text();
  void SetText(std::string&);

  void Move(const OrderedPair &_pos);
  void RMove(const OrderedPair &_pos);

  void Redraw();
  void Clear();
};
```

If this is too messy, or you think you need more information about my classes, ask me to add them here, or look at my GitHub repo (public) on the dev branch [here](http://www.github.com/Areuz/ncefmpp/tree/dev).

Comment: Can you give us minimal, complete, compilable code that we can use to replicate the problem?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz In all of my SO questions, I try to do that, but what am I supposed to do, when I don't know how to replicate it outside of this scenario? In this case, the problem was absolutely somewhere else than the error message pointed me to - It didn't error when it went out of bounds of the vector...

Comment: @areuz `_list.at(loop)` instead of `_list[loop]` would have identified the problem immediately.  Also, it isn't a good idea to name your variables with leading underscores, like `_list`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hmm, good to know, I will try that and maybe use that from now on. Why is it not good in your opinion? I use it, because it's the opposite of a member variable, which has a trailing underscore.

Comment: Use `at()` as a sanity check to ensure you're not going out of bounds.  Once you're sure of this, then change back to `[ ]`.  As to the leading underscore, names with leading underscores are reserved for the compiler's implementation.  I know there are rules where it is "safe" to use leading underscores, but they're too hard for me to remember, so I never use leading underscores.  A search on SO will direct you to threads that explain this.

Comment: [Here is a link to the rules for leading underscores](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hmm... I see. Alright I might have to change my habits.

Comment: @areuz Well that's the point of doing it. When you tried to strip the program down, at some point you would have removed the actual cause of the problem, and when that made the problem go away, you would have probably solved it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (unsigned int loop = size_; loop < (size_ + _list.size()); loop++) 
{
    [...] _list[loop] [...]
}
```

You set `size_` to `_list.size()` in the list constructor, so it means you start iterating your list from the end, and `_list[loop]` is out of bounds.

Didn't you mean this instead ?

```
for (unsigned int loop = 0 ; loop < _list.size() ; loop++) 
{
    [...] _list[loop] [...]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are accessing elements outside vector's range (`_list[loop]`):

```
for (unsigned int loop = size_; loop < (size_ + _list.size()); loop++) {
  list_.push_back(new Label(parent_, _list[loop], {pos_.y + (loop * spacing_), pos_.x}, maxsize_));
```

Answer (score 1):

Vendors of C++ implementations tend to apply a lot of effort to eliminating obvious flaws from their implementation of the standard library.   So the odds of the actual cause of your problem being a simple `std::string` assignment are vanishingly small (approximately zero).

What will almost certainly be happening is that some code in your program - executed BEFORE the assignment occurs - will be exhibiting undefined behaviour.   This might include falling off the end of an array (e.g. accessing `x[3]` where `x` is an array or a `std::vector` with less than three elements), dereferencing a null pointer, using an uninitialised variable.

One of the quainter properties of undefined behaviour is that the effect may not be immediate .... only for a crash to occur in some completely unrelated code that is subsequently executed.

This is almost certainly happening in your code.   You need to work backward - from the point where the crash occurs - to find the actual previously executed code statement (or code statements) that actually caused the problem.

This is one reason that advice on SO is to provide an MCVE - the process of cutting out extraneous code can allow you to find the actual cause.   If it doesn't, them someone has a fighting chance of helping you ... because you post code that actually exhibits the problem.     Which you haven't in this case.

In this case, the `for` loop is the culprit, since it is accessing more elements of a container than it has.